# Changing order of summation including a min in the summation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation, power-series, generating-functions

Lets say I have the following expression:

$$
h(x) =  \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{v=1}^{\min\{k,j\}} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}k!}{(k-v)!} {n \brack k}f(x)^{k-v}  B_{n,v}^f(x)
$$

Now my goal is to have the $v$ summation come before the $k$ summation, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

$h(x) 
=  \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{v=1}^{\min\{k,j\}} 
\frac{(-1)^{n-k}k!}{(k-v)!} {n \brack k}f(x)^{k-v}  B_{n,v}^f(x)
$

If $n \le j$,
since $k \le n$,
the sums become
$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{v=1}^{k} 
= \sum_{v=1}^{n} \sum_{k= v}^n 
$.

If $n > j$,
the sums could be split
into two parts like this:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{v=1}^{\min\{k,j\}} 
&=\sum_{k=1}^j \sum_{v=1}^{k} +\sum_{k=j+1}^n \sum_{v=1}^{j}\\
&= \sum_{v=1}^{j}\sum_{k=v}^j +\sum_{v=1}^{j} \sum_{k=j+1}^n
\end{align}

Comment: What about the terms within the summations, how would those change?

Comment: They would be the same. The parts of the terms that only involved v could be moved outside the inner summation.